# Laravel page refresh with out clicking refresh button in browser

Tags: php, google-chrome, laravel-5, sublimetext3

I'm doing a project in **`Laravel 5.1`**.I am  running the local development server through the command,

`php artisan serve`

After that i have done some changes in  **`sublime`** text editor, I get the desired results only after clicking the refresh button in my browser.But  i need to refresh the page when some  edits is in performed in my code instead of clicking the refresh button in the browser. 
Is there any feature/plugin for that?

Comment: While this is entirely opinionated, I've used [LiveReload](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LiveReload) successfully before.

Comment: i think this link will help you to http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_lastmodified.asp

Comment: @cfreear:I am using sublime text 3.There is is no LiveReload plugin for this version

Comment: @Roboticsexpert:I didnt get you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found [LiveReload](http://livereload.com/).It is not currently updated in documentation to work with Sublime Text 3.But now they rewrote the plugin for ST3.

https://github.com/dz0ny/LiveReload-sublimetext2/tree/devel

**Linux**

```
cd ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages
rm -rf LiveReload
git clone -b devel https://github.com/dz0ny/LiveReload-sublimetext2.git LiveReload
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply just do the following:

Run on our terminal:

```
npm install
```

to have your node dependencies installed elixir,gulp...etc

then open your `gulpfile.js` file and add the following:

```js
elixir(function (mix) {

    mix.browserSync({ proxy: 'foo.bar'});

});
```

then run in your terminal

```
gulp watch
```

Please note that you don't need the proxy leave it blank if you want so, only if you got your homestead or your development env with local domain and you wanted to use your domain instead of serve then replace the dummy domain with yours.

**btw:** the output of `gulp watch` won't help you with IPs generated therefore just use the port provided with it and not the IP, like so: `foo.bar:3000` and `foo.bar:3001`.

**Plus:** if you needed to access you project from other PC on LAN just add a port forwarding from within *Virtualbox* and forward 3000 to 3000

[image]

And for sure you won't do it like this every time you destroy/delete your vagrant/homestead! you've to add this port forwarding into your **homsetead** configurations that reside within `~/.homestead/Homestead.yaml`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I am not using Homestead

Comment: @Muhsin Sorry for that! I don't delete it, though! it might help others ;)  and for you: you are welcome buddy

Comment: I didn't try it without **Homestead** but to me it should work if you got  nodejs installed, give it a try and let me know please

Comment: :Thanks for your answer